Docker container doesn't keep up when deployed on swarm network
I have a docker container deployed on a swarm network that I initiated and updated using docker node update. The docker compose file is:
version: '3.8'

networks:
  test:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
services:
  identity_vdr:
    networks:
      - test
    image: identity_vdr:1.0
    ports:
      - "9701:9701"
      - "9702:9702"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == indy1]

And the Dockerfile:
# Uses the base image of Ubuntu 16.04
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Sets the non-interactive environment to avoid issues with prompts
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Updates the system and installs dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
    git \
    wget \
    vim \
    python3.5 \
    python3-pip \
    python-setuptools \
    python3-nacl \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates

# Updates pip and setuptools
RUN pip3 install -U 'pip<10.0.0' setuptools==44.0.0

# Adds the necessary keys for the Sovrin repositories
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys CE7709D068DB5E88 && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys BD33704C

# Adds the Sovrin repositories
RUN echo "deb https://repo.sovrin.org/deb xenial master" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb https://repo.sovrin.org/sdk/deb xenial master" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

# Updates the system again and installs the Hyperledger Indy packages
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
    indy-node=1.13.0~dev1213 \
    libindy-crypto=0.4.5 \
    python3-indy-crypto=0.4.5 \
    python3-orderedset=2.0 \
    python3-psutil=5.4.3 \
    python3-pympler=0.5 \
    indy-plenum=1.13.0~dev1021 \
    libindy=1.15.0~1536-xenial \
    indy-cli=1.15.0~1536-xenial

# Installs the python3-indy package
RUN pip3 install python3-indy==1.15.0

# Clones the GitHub repository
# RUN git clone https://github.com/timo-kang/Hyperledger-Indy-Tutorial.git /opt/Hyperledger-Indy-Tutorial
COPY . /opt/Hyperledger-Indy-Tutorial

# Updates the Indy configuration file
RUN awk '{if (index($1, "NETWORK_NAME") != 0) {print("NETWORK_NAME = \"sandbox\"")} else print($0)}' /etc/indy/indy_config.py > /tmp/indy_config.py && \
    mv /tmp/indy_config.py /etc/indy/indy_config.py

# Sets the working directory
WORKDIR /opt/Hyperledger-Indy-Tutorial

EXPOSE 9701 9702

# Sets the default command
CMD ["bash"]

I exposed these ports in the Dockerfile, and when I do build and run in this container, it works well. When I deploy the stack, no error message is shown, instead, the container finishes every few seconds and a new one is created automaticall:
ID             NAME                              IMAGE              NODE      DESIRED STATE   CURRENT STATE             ERROR     PORTS
g8exkoszfivi   node-1-stack_identity_vdr.1       identity_vdr:1.0   indy1     Running         Starting 1 second ago               
o7an7o4r4cnj    \_ node-1-stack_identity_vdr.1   identity_vdr:1.0   indy1     Shutdown        Complete 6 seconds ago              
ogwtjvct1d26    \_ node-1-stack_identity_vdr.1   identity_vdr:1.0   indy1     Shutdown        Complete 13 seconds ago             
qu0is4xgl3zq    \_ node-1-stack_identity_vdr.1   identity_vdr:1.0   indy1     Shutdown        Complete 21 seconds ago             
b7z9k3aqxok1    \_ node-1-stack_identity_vdr.1   identity_vdr:1.0   indy1     Shutdown        Complete 27 seconds ago  

The last command of my Docker file is CMD ["bash"] and I thought this could be the problem, but removing it didn't change anything. I wonder where I can check why the container does not stay up, as doing docker logs <ID> is not a valid command in a stack.

If your Dockerfile had CMD ["bash"] it sounds like it's meant for interactive use. That type of containers often just exit when there's no TTY attached to the container at startup. What does your container do? It would probably help if you edited your post and added your Dockerfile to it.

You probably want to set the image's CMD to directly run the program that's packaged in the image.

@HansKilian that's exactly the case, I wanted an interactive session (docker run -it... works fine). My container just install based on ubuntu 16.04 python and Hyperledger Indy dependencies, then on this interactive session I wanted to do things. I added the Dockerfile

You can add a dummy command to the Dockerfile that'll keep the container running. Then you can docker exec -it <container name> bash into it. If you use CMD tail -f /dev/null instead of the one you have now, the container should stay active. The command doesn't do anything, but it never finishes. So the container stays up.
